# Guess the technology

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I was just looking Christmas recipes and I noticed this URL.

[http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/search?dishes[]=mulled_wine](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/search?dishes%5b%5d=mulled_wine)

Can anyone tell me the technology this uses?

Obviously it's no guarantee but I'd be interested to know.

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about what technologies are in use on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the part after 'search?':

It's not a rewritten URL, it makes use of the fact that you can send 'arrays' of data via POST and GET by appending square brackets.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dishes[]" value="Potatoes">
<input type="checkbox" name="dishes[]" value="Chips">
<input type="checkbox" name="dishes[]" value="Grub">
```

If you were to check the first two, the URL will look like this (if using GET):

```
http://site.com/mypage?dishes[]=Potatoes&dishes[]=Chips
```

PHP (and other languages, probably) will automatically convert values like this into an array:

```
$_GET = array(
    ['dishes'] => array(
      [0] => 'Potatoes',
      [1] => 'Chips',
    )
)
```

The part before the GET parameters is easily achieved by RewriteRules in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule food/recipes/search some/folder/and/file.php [L,QSA]
```

This will make the URL appear like 'site.com/food/recipes/search' but the server will use the file 'some/folder/and/file.php'. [QSA] will make sure the GET parameters are properly passed to the rewritten URL.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks.  Something else to add to the 'must look at' list.

Answer (score 0):

HTML, CSS and JavaScript. There's no obvious way to tell what technologies are used on the backend - the site uses URL rewriting to make the URLs pretty, which incidentally erases the clues (such as file extensions); and the server itself returns minimal info about its innards.

Answer (score 0):

As this is tagged under URL & URL-Rewriting. I will be specific to that:-
Please see the place holder for dishes in Page

[image]

The url is used to manipulate the dishes portion of the Website.

Try manipulating the url to 
http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/search?dishes[]=apple_pie

and see the difference. I hope this helps.

This link might help you:-
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm